# Can't reach tomcat server remotely

Tags: java, tomcat, google-cloud-platform

I'm using a VM on Google Compute Engine, I chose a g1-small machine.

I installed tomcat server. The server do run, but I can't reach it on my web browser.

I also installed httpd and I can reach port 80 on my browser, but not 8080

This are my open ports:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1180/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1198/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1180/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1198/master         
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      11470/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      11470/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11319/httpd
```

This is my tomcat.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 8.5 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.56"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.56"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.56/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.56/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.56/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I already added port 8080 to firewall with the command

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

But when I list the firewall settings I get this

```
trusted (active)
 target: ACCEPT
 icmp-block-inversion: no
 interfaces: eth0
 sources: 
 services: http https
 ports: 
 protocols: 
 masquerade: no
 forward-ports: 
 source-ports: 
 icmp-blocks: 
 rich rules:
```

Comment: Just to check the basics: what URL are you using to reach the Tomcat welcome page? Something like `http://your_engine_ip_address_here:8080`? Or, if you have removed the welcome page from Tomcat, then: `http://your_engine_ip_address_here:8080/your_webapp_basename`?

Comment: I tried both, but none worked. It just says that the server took too long to respond. I believe its a network thing, because I also installed httpd and I can reach port 80

Comment: OK - understood. This is relevant new information. You should add it to the question.

Comment: Have you created a firewall rule to allow incoming connections to you VM instance port 8080 via GCP Firewall? Have a look at the documentation [Creating a firewall ingress rule](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall).

Comment: Thank you!! That solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue you should configure GCP Firewall to allow ingress connections to your Tomcat server.

Have a look at the documentation [Configuring Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall) and follow instruction [Creating a firewall ingress rule](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall#creating_a_firewall_ingress_rule) via Console or via command line:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create tomcat-server-allow-ingress --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:8080 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=tomcat-server
```

I'd recommend you to replace `0.0.0.0/0` with your IPs and use [network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) to apply your rule to your VM instance directly:

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags tomcat-server --zone=europe-west3-a --tags=tomcat-server
```